# OpenCV CUDA running slower than OpenCV CPU

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, parallel-processing

I've been struggling to get OpenCV CUDA to improve performance for things like erode/dilate, frame differencing etc when i read in a video from an avi file. typical i get half the FPS on the GPU (580gtx) than on the CPU (AMD 955BE). Before u ask if i'm measuring fps correctly, you can clearly see the lag on the GPU with the naked eye especially when using a high erode/dilate level.

It seems that i'm not reading in the frames in parallel?? Here is the code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::gpu;

Mat cpuSrc;
GpuMat src, dst;

int element_shape = MORPH_RECT;

//the address of variable which receives trackbar position update
int max_iters = 10;
int open_close_pos = 0;
int erode_dilate_pos = 0;

// callback function for open/close trackbar
void OpenClose(int)
{
     IplImage disp;
     Mat temp;
    int n = open_close_pos - max_iters;
    int an = n > 0 ? n : -n;
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(element_shape, Size(an*2+1, an*2+1), Point(an, an) );
    if( n < 0 )
        cv::gpu::morphologyEx(src, dst, CV_MOP_OPEN, element);
    else
        cv::gpu::morphologyEx(src, dst, CV_MOP_CLOSE, element);

    dst.download(temp);
    disp = temp;    
   // cvShowImage("Open/Close",&disp);
}

// callback function for erode/dilate trackbar
void ErodeDilate(int)
{
     IplImage disp;
     Mat temp;
    int n = erode_dilate_pos - max_iters;
    int an = n > 0 ? n : -n;
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(element_shape, Size(an*2+1, an*2+1), Point(an, an) );
    if( n < 0 )
        cv::gpu::erode(src, dst, element);
    else
        cv::gpu::dilate(src, dst, element);
    dst.download(temp);
    disp = temp;    
    cvShowImage("Erode/Dilate",&disp);
}


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    VideoCapture capture("TwoManLoiter.avi");

    //create windows for output images
    namedWindow("Open/Close",1);
    namedWindow("Erode/Dilate",1);

    open_close_pos = 3;
    erode_dilate_pos = 0;
    createTrackbar("iterations", "Open/Close",&open_close_pos,max_iters*2+1,NULL);
    createTrackbar("iterations", "Erode/Dilate",&erode_dilate_pos,max_iters*2+1,NULL);

    for(;;)
    {

         capture >> cpuSrc;
         src.upload(cpuSrc);
         GpuMat grey;
         cv::gpu::cvtColor(src, grey, CV_BGR2GRAY); 
         src = grey;

        int c;

        ErodeDilate(erode_dilate_pos);
        c = cvWaitKey(25);

        if( (char)c == 27 )
            break;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The CPU implementation is the same minus using namespace cv::gpu and the Mat instead of GpuMat of course.

Thanks

Comment: What resolution is your video?

Comment: 640x480 ...as i increase the amount of erosion or dilation the GPU slows down exponentially more than the CPU. the GPU is actually slightly faster the the CPU when using a low dilate/erode value

Answer (score 6):

My guess would be, that the performance gain from the GPU erode/dilate is overweighted by the memory operations of transferring the image to and from the GPU every frame. Keep in mind that memory bandwidth is a crucial factor in GPGPU algorithms, and even more the bandwidth between CPU and GPU.

**EDIT:** To optimize it you might write your own image display routine (instead of cvShowImage) that uses OpenGL and just displays the image as an OpenGL texture. In this case you don't need to read the processed image from the GPU back to CPU and you can directly use an OpenGL texture/buffer as a CUDA image/buffer, so you don't even need to copy the image inside the GPU. But in this case you might have to manage CUDA resources yourself. With this method you might also use PBOs to upload the video into the texture and profit a bit from asynchronity.

Comment: Interesting and sounds like a possibility. Just curious, is it possible with CUDA to allocate images in GPU memory and DMA them right there on capture/load?

Comment: I agree with Christian. It seems you are using a 1x1 filter, the execution of which will be done in almost no time at all. Also, you are copying a lot of data to the GPU, which you won't need (BGR, while you only need gray). Processing these images on the GPU will only pay off if you do more than this very simple dilate/erosion, otherwise copying the data will take longer than the execution.

Comment: Even absent the consideration of memcpy overhead: for operations like image morphology, it is very difficult for the GPU to compete with SSE2-optimized CPU code.  The CPU can do sixteen (16) bytewise min/max operations in a single instruction, and runs at 5x the clock rate of a GPU. For workloads that involve operating on lots of regular, narrow integers, the GPU can only hope to achieve parity.

With SM 2.1, Fermi added support for "video instructions" that enable some 4-way SIMD operations on bytes in 32-bit registers, but perhaps OpenCV does not yet implement support for those.

Comment: Oh i see. thanks guys. will take everything said into consideration and let you all know whether is worked out :) OpenGL wasn't my focus, but your comment really has got me to consider it.