# No performance gain with OpenCV 3.2 on OpenCL (TAPI)

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

Absolute TAPI beginner here. I recently ported my CV code to make use of UMat intstead of Mat since my CPU was on it's limit, especially morphologic operations seemed to consume quite some computing power.

Now with UMat I cannot see any changes in my framerate, it is *exactly* the same no matter if I use UMat or not, also Process Explorer reports no GPU usage whatsoever. I did a small test with a few calls of dilation and closing on a full HD image -- no effect.

Am I missing something here? I'm using the latest OpenCV 3.2 build for Windows and a GTX 980 with driver 378.49. `cv::ocl::haveOpenCL()` and `cv::ocl::useOpenCL()` both return `true` and `cv::ocl::Context::getDefault().device( 0 )` also gives me the correct device, everything looks good as far as I can tell. Also, I'm using some custom CL code via `cv::ocl::Kernel` which is definitely invoked.

I realize it is a naive way of thinking that just changing Mat to UMat will result in huge performance gain (although every of the the very limited number of ressources covering TAPI I find online suggests exactly that). Still, I was hoping to get *some* gain for starters and then further optimize step-by-step from there. However, the fact that I can't discover any GPU usage whatsoever highliy irritates me.

Is there something I have to watch out for? Maybe my usage of TAPI prevents from a streamlined execution of OpenCL code, maybe by accidental/hidden readbacks I'm not aware of? Do you see any way of profiling the code with respect to that matter?

Are there any how-to's, best practices or common pitfalls for using TAPI? Things like "don't use local UMat instances within functions", "use `getUMat()` instead of `copyTo()`", "avoid calls of function x since it will cause a `cv::ocl::flush()`", things of that sort?

Are there OpenCV operations that are not ported to OpenCL yet? Is there documentation accordingly? In the OpenCV source code I saw that, if built with `HAVE_OPENCL` flat, the functions try to run CL code using the `CV_OCL_RUN` macro, however there are a few conditions checked beforehand, otherwise it falls back to CPU. It does not seem like I have any possitility to figure out if the GPU or the CPU was actually used apart from stepping into each and every OpenCL function with the debugger, am I right?

Any ideas/experiences apart from that? I'd appreciate any input that relates to this matter.

Comment: did you test whether speedup is achieved for some code other people already tried? like: https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-transparent-api/ If you get the speedup there, you might have some problem in your code or your processing chain isn't suited for GPU processing. Could be helpful to see your actual code.

Comment: If possible use nvprof to profile your code and see what is going wrong. Documentation can be found here http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/#axzz4ba1GShPU

Comment: @Micka yes, I did that and found that for simple stuff such as color conversion there is indeed performance gain. But the in my code it's the morphologic operations that hurt the most, and there is no noticable effect there.

Comment: @OutOfBound Thanks, I'm now using Nsight since it's got great Visual Studio integration. I tried the standalone nvvp but it keeps crashing. From the output I found that some morph kernels were not invoked due to this condition: `if (localThreads[0]*localThreads[1] * 2 < (localThreads[0] + ksize.width - 1) * (localThreads[1] + ksize.height - 1)) return false;` in `ocl_morphOp`. What I find quite unfortunate is that the ocl code is just skipped silently and there is no way for me to recognize that the processing is actually done on CPU. Also, the condition is hardcoded. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: What strikes me from the Nsight output is that there seems to be a new Kernel ID for each invocation of the `morph` kernel (in a for loop doing morphologyEx + cvtColor: morph kid=1, RGB kid=2, morph kid=3, RGB kid=4, and so on). This is in contrast to OpenCL samples I downloaded from elsewhere. Program ID stays the same, though. Although I must say I don't know what the "Kernel ID" actually refers to and there is no documentation to be found. Maybe this hints toward an accidental re-creation of cl kernel objects every time? Does anybody know what a Kernel ID is?

Comment: have a look at the answer and expecially the comments on that answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526786/opencv-cuda-running-slower-than-opencv-cpu they say that morphological operations might be not so well suited for GPU because SSE instructions of the CPU might outperform the GPU easily. But I'm not deep enough into openCVs gpgu functons. But afair, opencv/opencl use some old compute capability support of cuda.

Comment: some of the operations is not that "transparent" to opencl gpu code. I am dreaming about a list of supported opencl functions and how much its faster. Apparently, there is not...